# Styling Roads in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am building a style to work with vector tiles.

My road geometries are many linestrings in a single layer.

I want to style the roads by rendering a casing, fill and centreline from one geometry.

I have a style that looks like:-

```
 var style = function(feature,resolution) {

        var line_casing_stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color : '', width : 1, lineCap : 'round'}),
            line_fill_stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color : '', width : 1, lineCap : 'round'});

        var style_array = [], length = 0;

            if (properties.layer == 'roads') {

                line_casing_stroke.setWidth(5);
                line_casing_stroke.setColor(colour_map.road.casing);
                line_fill_stroke.setWidth(4);
                line_fill_stroke.setColor(colour_map.road.fill);

                style_array[length++] = line_casing;
                style_array[length++] = line_fill;
        }

        return style_array;
 }
```

This creates a result as shown in the picture below which I think is caused by the lineCap: round in the casing style making the geometry a little but longer. Is there a way to get round this or a better approach? Note that I  CANNOT join the geometries in the vector tiles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a simple fix. Styles can have a zIndex

```
var line_casing_stroke = 
new ol.style.Stroke({color : '', width : 1, lineCap : 'round', zIndex: 0 }),
line_fill_stroke = 
new ol.style.Stroke({color : '', width : 1, lineCap : 'round', zIndex: 1});
```

Comment: Isn't the zIndex is a property of the Style, not the Stroke?